# How to initial data into mongodb with mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongoengine

I'm using mongoengine to connect MongoDB as orm tools in my current project.
Does mongoengine provide a way to create schema and load initial data after application startup ?
Even if mongoengine can't do that, is there another way to work for it all the same?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/import-export/#ImportExportTools-mongoimport) from mongodb to import data.

```
mongoimport --collection collection --file collection.json
```

Also, you can load a script containing inserts like this:

```
mongo --quiet script.js
```

In `script.js` you can have something like the following:

```
db.users.insert({name:"homer", email:"homer@spm.com"});
```

So you can build a python script to call that for you. If you are using Django you can use this library to [call a hook after syndb](https://github.com/podshumok/django-post-syncdb-hooks). You can try [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/) to automate the initial data process for you.